# Entity Framework: Deleting multiple objects query

Tags: entity-framework

I have a List which hold the PK ID's of a number of objects in a collection that I want to remove. Does anyone know how to write a single query to retrieve these objects?

Eg:

```
IList<int> objectList; // populated with int Primary key Ids

using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities()){

    var result = context.MyObjectCollection.Where(obj=> obj.ID IN objectList);

    foreach(var item in result){
        context.DeletObject(item);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = context.MyObjectCollection.Where(obj=> objectList.Contains(obj.ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Mel's answer doesn't work because in .NET 3.5 SP1 the EF doesn't know how to translate list.Contains(...) into T-SQL. Although this is coming in 4.0.

The workaround is to manually produce a big OR query i.e.

```
Where(obj => obj.ID == item1 || obj.ID == item2 ....)
```

Here is a tip I wrote that makes that easy:

[Tip 8 - How to write where IN style queries using LINQ to Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx)

Hope this helps

Alex James

Entity Framework Team - Read my [Entity Framework Tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://efe.codeplex.com

```
this.Devices.Update(o => new Device() { LastOrderRequest = DateTime.Now, Description = "teste" }, o => o.Id == 1);
```